# How can I save my custom data to a text file?

Tags: java, android, saving-data

I'm developing an application that helps in my own business (billing application) and I need to store the data in the device. I need to save especially to a text file, but I don't know what I have to do.
The data type I have to save:

```
(mydata.txt)
##
id:1
heatUsage:2123
waterUsage:45,4
##
id:2
heatUsage:4572
waterUsage:21,2
##
id:3
heatUsage:456
waterUsage:11,4
##
```

Can anyone know how to save this file programmaticly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this might be useful to you.
You can format data like:

```
    public String formatData(List<User> users) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            stringBuilder.append("##\n");
            stringBuilder.append("id:" + user.getId() + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append("heatUsage:" + user.getHeatUsage() + "\n");
            stringBuilder.append("waterUsage:" + user.getWaterUsage() + "\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

And Write to file:

```
private void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("filename.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```